# Richtext-field in Sitecore not showing medialibrary image from HTML

Tags: c#, asp.net, sitecore, sitecore6

I seem to be having an interesting problem. 
I have the following setup.

There is an email template which contains some single-line text fields and 1 rich text field.

I filled the item created from this template with some information.
Now I've got sender , receiver , cc , bcc fields all of which are single-line text fields except for one, that's the  message field(this one is a rich text field). This field has been populated which HTML which all works fine except when I want to add an image from my media library.

http://postimg.org/image/moiew26fx/

Now I can see the image in my item appearing except when I test it ( an email will be sent to my inbox), I can see the entire mail with html markup except my image seems to have been removed. When I insert another image in my markup ( a random one from the internet ) all seems good. 
Does anyone have an idea what happens here in the richtext field and why it refuses to output my image.

Running version: Sitecore.NET 6.6.0

EDIT : 
I found a situation quite similar to mine here : 
http://sdn.sitecore.net/SDN5/Forum/ShowPost.aspx?PostID=12071

Comment: Yes , that makes a lot of sense ( also from what I concluded from my update that I just posted ). Thank you for your reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The post on sdn you found is correct. The url of the image needs to be an absolute url. As you mentioned you have this email template but from the context I don’t know how it will be consumed.  You can handle this on item saving event or before the email send action.

As in SDN post said customize rich text editor is not easy also you don’t want all the image to use absolute url which might take time in case you need to do content marination to a different domain in the future. You can add a custom insert image button only available to this template where you use  absolute url instead.

But update the media url before sending the email action seems the easiest way to go.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that your image contains only relative path without host name.

That's why you see it in **Sitecore**, but you don't see it in your email box.

You will need to process the html before sending and add `http://your.domain.com` to all relative paths.

Comment: correct. And I'm working on trying to get that working.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be an issue with the configuration of Email Campaign Manager. Follow these steps

1. Go to Email Campaign Manager.
2. Select Content tab.
3. Check the value of Base URL- default address for all links field.

If it is set to some website URL other than your website URL change it to your website URL.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I'm definately going to look into that.